# strtok segmentation fault, just gives a segmentation fault when the first line of input file is blank

Tags: c, linux, segmentation-fault, aix

I am using AIX. There are several posts of Segmentation fault with strtok but I could not find any to help me.

I am writing a c program and I want to read a file in the program and then sort this line (I just need the minutes and the seconds at the end of the second line).

here is a snippet from my code:

```
   FILE *timeFile;
   int x, timeElapsed;
   char line[1000], *temp;

  int main()
  {
        x = 0; 
        timeFile= fopen("time.txt", "r");

        if(timeFile==NULL)
        {
            printf("\nerror opening file time.txt\n");
            printf("\nPlease update system time manually\n");
            return 1;//error
        }

        while( x<10 && fgets(line, sizeof(line), timeFile)!= NULL)

        {

            if( x==1 )//we need data from the second line
            {

                temp        =   strtok(line, "  ");

                printf("\nline: %s",line);//the Output here is as expected 'line: real'
                printf("\ntemp: %s",temp);//the error occurs here at temp


                break;
             }
            x++;

        }
}
```

The file I am trying to read is has this inside:

```
real    0m1.25s
user    0m0.09s
sys 0m0.02s
```

The first line is blank (only a return character I think) and 'real 0m1.25s
' is the second line. I want to read only the second line. The error occurs when I try to read the temp variable.

The funny thing is I have used nearly the same code for the same job in another program and it worked. The only difference was that in the input file of the previous project there were no blank lines or tabs. So I am confused please help.

PS: I am using a German keyboard so it capitalizes words on its own, sorry about that.

Comment: Always check `strtok()` for `NULL`. Also, note that your `while` loop is absurd.

Comment: Would you please elaborate?

Comment: I think my comment is very clear, you have to check that `temp` is not `NULL` after `strtok()` and the absurd loop thing I think is quite evident. You loop to get the second line only, what I would is `fgets()` once to skip the first and then `fgets()` again to get the second, didn't you think of that? and in general if you want to skip `n` lines do `for (int i = 0 ; ((i < n) && (fgets(line, sizeof(line), file) != NULL)) ; ++i) ;`.

Comment: I know about the while loop, I just copied everything from the previous projec. Don't worry about that I will take care of it. For temp I think since the line is 'real' shouldn't temp also be 'real'. In any case how do I check if temp is NULL other than printf.

Comment: No point in using `strtok()` (which has a pretty bad reputation) for this, consider using `sscanf()`.

Comment: DO NOT ASSUME ANYTHING EVER WHEN WRITING A PROGRAM. !!!!! The input file might be corrupted and the line you read doesn't have any `" "` character thus `strtok()` is failing and since you assume it's not you try to read from a `NULL` pointer.

Comment: `strtok()` is fine if you understand what it does and how to use it.  It is suitable for some tasks that are a bit tricky for `sscanf()`.  On the other hand, this is not one of those tasks.

Comment: @iharob, absence of any of the delimiter characters in the string does not cause `strtok()` to fail.  `strtok()` does return `NULL` when there are no more tokens, but it is debatable whether that should be characterized as a failure.  That will happen on the first call only in the event that the string contains no characters that are not in the delimiter list, but indeed it will happen in that case, so yes, it is important to check for that.

Comment: Couldn't compile your program, it is incomplete. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use [`sscanf()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html) instead. Try to avoid `strtok()` at all costs unless otherwise absolutely neccessary.

[Here is a link to source you might find useful](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_sscanf.htm)